# Excel, get SUM of Cells leading up to cell matching another cell

Tags: excel, google-docs

I have an Excel Spreadsheet (technically it is a Google Docs sheet, but the functions are pretty much identical.. )

Now in one Sheet, I have a list of cells.

> A2 - K2. Each one of these has a number (1-10). This will be called the **Index**

Beneath those, each cell has a value, so..

> A3 - K3. Each one also has a number (a value. Not 1-10, but arbitrary). This is called the **Value**.

Now then, in another Sheet, I need to be able to type in a Number that will corrospond to the A2-K2 **Index** and get the **Summation** of *all values up to and including* that Index. So then, assume the following...

```
   A   B    C   D
1  1   2    3   4
2  2   4    6   10
```

If I put in **3** in one cell, then beneath it, I want to get the value **SUM(2+4+6)**. So the cell would show **12**. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do this without just outright hard-coding every single one in. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you could use this formula:

```
=SUMIF(A1:J1;"<="&L2;A2:J2)
```

Where L2 is the cell where you will type in the index number.